# Select from multiple partitions in Cassandra, with a composite partition key?

Tags: cassandra, cql

In Cassandra (CQL), it's possible to query multiple partitions like for example:

```
create table foo(i int, j int, primary key (i));
insert into foo (i, j) values (1, 1);
insert into foo (i, j) values (2, 2);

select * from foo where i in (1, 2);

 i | j
---+---
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
```

However, if `foo` has a composite partition key, I'm not sure if it's possible:

```
create table foo(i int, j int, k int, primary key ((i, j), k));
```

Some queries I've tried, which CQL has rejected are:

```
select * from foo where (i = 1 and j = 1) or (i = 2 and j = 2);

select * from foo where (i, j) in ((1, 1), (2, 2));
```

I've also tried:

```
select * from foo where i in (1, 2) and j in (1, 2);
```

but this is too wide of a query, since this will also return values where (i=1, j=2) or (i = 2, j=1).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to query in clause from client side using  DSE Java Driver .You have to use async option
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/async/